# Octave crashes due to clearing variables in script without breakpoints - Attempts to write to last memory block

Tags: memory, crash, octave, breakpoints

On my system (Windows, 8 GB RAM 64-bit i7), Octave is having this problem handling medium sized arrays. I have task manager open, and the memory never going beyond 200 MB before the graphing section. It will often crash around 150 MB. The interesting thing is that if I put breakpoints into my code to find where the problem lies, the problem goes away, and I am actually able to get through everything, and move on to the graphing portion. It also crashes through that unless I add breakpoints every other graph.

With breakpoints, I am able to load it up to the full script load which should be around 1 GB. I'm not crazy right? This is supposed to be easy stuff that Matlab would breeze through in a second.

Below is a snippit of code that will crash unless I use breakpoints at every double new line.

```
n2040id = fopen(n_20to40ft_file);
n2040data = dlmread(n2040id,',', [8 1 70849 98]);
fclose(n2040id);
n20test = n2040data(3410:22066,:);
n30test = n2040data(26730:45748,:);
n40test = n2040data(49874:68706,:);
clear n2040data;

%% 20Ft Test Processing
n20spo2 = n20test(:,88);
n20spo2(n20spo2 == 0) = [];
n20co = n20test(:,89);
n20co(n20co == 0) = [];
clear n20test;

%% 30 Ft Test Processing
n30spo2 = n30test(:,88);
n30spo2(n30spo2 == 0) = [];
n30co = n30test(:,89);
n30co(n30co == 0) = [];
clear n30test;

%% 40 Ft Test Processing
n40spo2 = n40test(:,88);
n40spo2(n40spo2 == 0) = [];
n40co = n40test(:,89);
n40co(n40co == 0) = [];
clear n40test;
```

This snippit uses about an extra 60-90 MB of memory when compared to the memory before that point which is cleared before every break when I am done with it. The first array is a double of size 70841x98 while the others become around 450x1 to 900x1. These are not difficult arrays to deal with by a long shot. Yet it will crash unless I put in those breakpoints, then I can just press continue and it's fine.

I've also tried using `clear -v` but that crashed too unless I used breakpoints.

Now, I debugged with visual studio and got this error:
`No symbol file loaded for liboctgui-3.dll` as well as and error that it was trying to access `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` and it got "permission denied" trying to access it. Why on earth would it be trying to access the last memory block?

This actually doesn't happen if I don't clear any variables. It will take up the extra 1 -1.4 GB happily. Is this a known issue? releasing memory shouldn't cause a program to attempt to access the very last possibly memory block.